# Is this $SL_3(\mathbb{F_2})$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$SL_3(\mathbb{F_2})$ is the set of all invertible $3x3$ matrices over the field $F_2$ with determinant $1$. From what I understand $F_2$ is the set $\{0, 1\}$, ie.. $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $2$.

As far as I can see then, $SL_3(\mathbb{F_2})$  has to be $$I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

If the $1$'s were in any other location we would have zero determinant. So is this $SL_3(\mathbb{F_2})$?

Comment: No. Look at the (other) permutation or upper/lower triangular matrices for instance. (Also note that the special and general linear groups are the same over $\Bbb F_2$, and $\times$ can be typeset with `\times`.) Why exactly do you think $1$'s anywhere else will cause zero determinant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete list of total 168 elements of $SL(3,2) = SL_{3}(\Bbb{F}_2)$. I hope you may get some ideas on what is going on in $SL(3,2)$ from this.

[image]

(Or you can just play '*Where's Waldo?*' game with Waldo replaced by the identity matrix $I_3$!)

Comment: But isn't don't the elements of $SL(3,2) = SL_{3}(\Bbb{F}_2)$ have to have $1$ as their determinant? Many of those matrices have $-1$ as a determinant?

Comment: By the way, how did you generate all those matrices...I'm guessing it wasn't by hand!

Comment: @sonicboom, In $\Bbb{F}_2$ we have $-1 = 1$. And I used *Mathematica 8.0* to find them all.

Comment: @sos440 +1 for the complete list

Comment: OK cheers. So over $\mathbb{F_2}$, $SL(3,2)$ has order $168$. But $GL(3,2)$ over $\mathbb{F_2}$ also has order $168$, so I take it over this particular field, the general linear subgroup and it's special linear group are equivalent?

Comment: @sonicboom, That is exactly what anon pointed out.

Comment: And @JayeshBadwaik, thanks for your precious upvote!

Comment: @sos440@: Ah yes I see he did mention it, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll have to have a look into mathematica...I don't think matlab can do this kind of thing..ie outputting a list of elements of a group.